# Kohana/PHP - Managing Notifications Messages

Tags: php, kohana

I'm developing custom web application  - at the same time - I'm learning a lot.

I'm on the stage where I need some community tips.

I'd like to standarize errors/notifications management in my app so I'm using Notify module.

Let's say I have a module `items`, in this module I got view() method.

First of all, I'm querying DB for specific item:

```
$item = ORM::factory('item', $id);

if( $item->loaded() )
{
    return $item;
}
else
{
    return Notice::msg('No items found', 'success');
}
```

then in my view:

```
<?php if( Notice::count() ) { ?>
    <?php echo Notice::render(); ?>
<?php } else { 
    <?php echo $content ?>
} ?>
```

Now there's my question. Is it correct approach? Do you have any techniques worth *copying*?

**Edit**
According to Zombor's answer the following solution would be more elegant, isn't it?
Model:
    $item = ORM::factory('item', $id);

```
if( !$item->loaded() )
{
    return false;
}
else
{
    return $item;
}
```

Controller:

```
if( !$model->method()->loaded() )
{
    Notice::msg('No items found', 'success');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only use the notice class in your controller really. Assign data to it by inspecting model results, then read from it and assign that output to your view directly. Don't use the class right in your view.

This will make your code more reusable, easier to read and easier to manage.

Comment: I edited my question. Can you take a look and comment this approach?

Comment: Yep, thats generally better, but you'll get an error if you return false from your model, and then try and check ->loaded() on that in your controller. You can probably just remove the ->loaded() check in your controller.